# Embed an image into div

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a Django project and I'm using the [blog example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/blog/) from Bootstrap 5

I'm trying to embed an image into the first div. So it goes from this:

[image: Before]

To this:

It's photoshopped.
[image]

How can I do that?

This is the div I'm trying to edit:

```html
    <div class="p-4 p-md-5 mb-4 rounded text-bg-dark">
            <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
                <h1 class="display-4 text-white fst-italic">We are opening our 4th location in March 2023</h1>
                <p class="lead my-3">Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers quickly and
                    efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.</p>
                <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white fw-bold">Continue reading...</a></p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The full example code can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v5.0.2/bootstrap-5.0.2-examples.zip).

Comment: did you try to search for div background image?

Comment: @DiegoD of course. I always search before posting, but I could not find what I was looking for in this case.

Comment: It seems you didn’t do a very good job with your search considering that the solution was background-image. And those were the two words inside the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a background property to the div:

```
<div style="background-image: URL('www.server.address/image.jpg');">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want the `background` property, you can attach a URL to it.
You may then want to [Apply a filter to a background image](https://css-tricks.com/apply-a-filter-to-a-background-image/)

```css
.headerObject {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url("https://cataas.com/cat");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerObject">
  Hello World
</div>
```